# A question about covering spaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

> > Let $p : (\widetilde X, \widetilde {x_0}) \longrightarrow (X,x_0)$ be a covering map where $\widetilde X$ is path connected and let $p_{*}$ be the induced homomorphism under $p$. Then show that the index of $p_{*} (\pi_{1} (\widetilde X, \widetilde {x_0}))$ in $\pi_{1} (X,x_0)$  is same as that of the cardinality of $p^{-1} (x_0)$.

How can I proceed? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: path-connectedness condition?

Comment: Do you know that the fundamental group of the base acts on the fibre?

Comment: I have proved that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ acts on $p^{-1} (x_0)$ transitively since $\widetilde X$ is path connected.

Comment: Hint: Orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Comment: So clearly $\mathrm {Orb}_{\widetilde {x_0}} = p^{-1} (x_0)$. So I think that I have to somehow use orbit stabilizer theorem. I found that the stabilizer of $\widetilde {x_0}$ contains those $[f]$ in $\pi_1 (X,x_0)$ whose lifts are loops based at $\widetilde {x_0}$.

Comment: What is $p_{*} (\pi_1 (\widetilde X, \widetilde {x_0}))$?

Comment: It will also contain the homotopic classes of loops based at $x_0$ whose lifts are also loops based at $\widetilde {x_0}$.

Comment: Hence $\mathrm {Stab} (\widetilde {x_0}) =  p_{*} (\pi_1 (\widetilde X, \widetilde {x_0}))$.

Comment: Can I say what I have written in my last comment @Michael Burr? Then we are through.

Comment: It would be better if you put your comments into your question and asked for proof verification.  Your ideas are right, but explaining them and turning them into a single coherent argument would be better.